# Wordpress - category__in is not listing on $wp_query with SEO urls

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a very simple plugin:

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'post_page');

function post_page()
{

 global $wp_query;      
 if(is_category())
 {
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($wp_query);
    exit;
 }

}
```

I have to get the category ids within my plugin. I am getting without SEO urls but category__in is empty with SEO urls

Without SEO friendly url (category__in not empty) :

http://phpxpert.com/?cat=3

With seo friendly url (category__in is empty):

http://phpxpert.com/category/jquery/

Why this is happening and how can I get post_id and category_ids in my plugin?

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll probably find the category being used in the `category_name` variable. You can then use [`get_term_by`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_by) to get more information about the category.